# UIActivity indicator or spinner in this case indicator is not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, uiactivity

So, I have written a program 
that is a map app which allows user to see there location 
when they open the app and when they double tap it allows them to drop a pin 
the bottom view which is hidden shows up and i want to show images in that view since i made the hight of the view really small i cant use storyboard to add components in it and i added a activity indicator
with code but for some reason the activity indicator is not showing up on the screen 
even when the hight of the hidden view changes and it comes up. this is the code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
class MapVC: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var pullUpViewHighConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var pullUpView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
let regiounRadius: Double = 1000
var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView?
var progrssLabel: UILabel?
var screen = UIScreen.main.bounds



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    configureLocationServices()
    addDoubleTap()
}


func addDoubleTap() {
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(droupPin(sender:)))
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTap.delegate = self

    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
}

func addSwipe() {
    let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(animateViewDown))
    swipe.direction = .down
    pullUpView.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
}

func animateViewUp() {
    pullUpViewHighConstraint.constant = 300
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}

@objc func animateViewDown() {
    pullUpViewHighConstraint.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func addSpinner() {
    spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    spinner?.center = CGPoint(x: screen.width / 2 -  (spinner?.frame.width)! / 2, y: 150)
    spinner?.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
    spinner?.color = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    spinner?.stopAnimating()
    pullUpView.addSubview(spinner!)
}


@IBAction func centerMapBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if authStatus == .authorizedAlways || authStatus ==  .authorizedWhenInUse{
        centerMapOnUserLocation()
        // removePin()

    }else {return}
}

}

 extension MapVC: MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    let pinAnnotation = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "droppablePin")
    pinAnnotation.pinTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9771530032, green: 0.7062081099, blue: 0.1748393774, alpha: 1)
    pinAnnotation.animatesDrop = true
    return pinAnnotation
}

func centerMapOnUserLocation() {
    guard let coordinets = locationManager.location?.coordinate else    { return }
    let coordinateRegion =    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinets, regiounRadius*2.0,  regiounRadius*2.0)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}

@objc func droupPin(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    removePin()
    animateViewUp()
    addSwipe()
    addSpinner()
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: mapView)
    let touchCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
    let annotation = DroppablePin(coordinatee: touchCoordinate, identifierr: "droppablePin")
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let coordinateRegion =  MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(touchCoordinate, regiounRadius*2.0, regiounRadius*2.0)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

}

func removePin() {
    for annotation in mapView.annotations {
        mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}

}

extension MapVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func configureLocationServices() {
    if authStatus == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    else {
        return
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    centerMapOnUserLocation()
}

}
```

Comment: Never upload code on an external website. Include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question itself using proper code formatting.

Comment: @DávidPásztor how do i edit the question

Comment: And you could split up that enormous first sentence into smaller ones to increase readability.. (there is an edit button under your question)

Comment: he says the spinner is not showing

Comment: @MilanNosáľ right now none

Comment: @MilanNosáľ ok now the first one is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the spinner is not showing because you don't position it correctly , Second you should use `startAnimating()` to animate the spinner  , Here you try to position the spinner in middle x,y of the pullView

```
    spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView() 
    spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false     
    spinner?.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
    spinner?.color =  colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    pullUpView.addSubview(spinner!)
   // center in container
    spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pullUpView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pullUpView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    spinner?.startAnimating()
```

This is the best time to use auto-layout as while you use frame-layout to show the `spinner` the `pullUpView` frame is changed which will result in an incorrect render , put with auto-layout it will render perfectly

Comment: i copied and pasted your code it still doesn't appear

Answer (score 1):

Replace `spinner?.stopAnimating()` with `spinner?.startAnimating()`, you don't want it stopped but running.

Comment: did that still doesn't appear to work please help and now the code is with the question

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work the first answer is working